POST Request isnt Working in React Native
useEffect(() => {
    function GetPostSessionData() {
      let data = new FormData();

      data.append("box_id", "8c457cf6-e5d3-5549-9edf-2ad999f4f870");
      data.append("device_type", "83");
      data.append("source", "XYZ");


      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        header: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      };

      fetch(
       baseURl,
        requestOptions
      )
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log(result, "result >>"))
        .catch((error) => console.log("error>>", error));
    }
    GetPostSessionData()
  }, []);

response > Request is missing required form field 'box_id' result >>,
Am able to get correct response in Postman.
Url and other details are correct, am not sure am binding correct form data.
Suggest some Solution
I have also used axios with async await and all , it gives same response
"Request is missing required form field 'box_id'"

Remove the content-type request header. The device should be able to send the correct header automatically

If that doesn't work, are you sure you're meant to be sending multipart/form-data and not application/x-www-form-urlencoded? There's no file upload involved

i removed content type request header but still am getting same response, and there no file upload , only box_id, devce_type and source , in form data

Yes, I realise there's no file upload so why are you using multipart/form-data? Is that what you're using in Postman? Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of your Postman request configuration

Chances are you're using application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman and not multipart/form-data.
FormData and its associated content-type multipart/form-data are primarily used for uploading files or other binary content. Since you are just sending plain strings, it seems likely that you need something simpler.
fetch(baseURl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    box_id: "8c457cf6-e5d3-5549-9edf-2ad999f4f870",
    device_type: "83",
    source: "XYZ",
  }),
});

When the request body is of type URLSearchParams, the default content-type header values is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
